# Responsive table overflow on mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Check out this image:

[image]

See how "Recreation", "Wednesday: 4:00-6:00pm" are spilling over into the next line under the column header? How do I keep the cell contents organized in the same column? It just looks very messy at the moment. I'm using jQuery mobile's default implementation of responsive tables.

```
<table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Activity Type</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Website</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm appending the cell contents dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap text in `span` and apply the below CSS, only on small screens.

```
@media (min-width: 35em) {
   .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive td span,
   .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive th span {
      width: 50%;
      text-align: left;
      float: right;
   }
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vk020c5u/)**